# Python 3 threads performance issue

Tags: python-3.x

I created two `threads` and executed them in `parallel` but astonishingly it took `more time` (`33.5 secs`) than `sequential` execution (`29.4 secs`). Please advice what am doing **wrong**?

```
def write_File(fName):
        start = timeit.default_timer()
        print('writing to {}!\n'.format(fName))
        with open(fName, 'a') as f:
                for i in range(0, 10000000):
                        f.write("aadadadadadadadadadadadada" + str(i));
        end = timeit.default_timer()
        print(end - start)
        print('Fn exit!')

start = timeit.default_timer()
t1 = Thread(target=write_File, args=('test.txt',))
t1.start()

t2 = Thread(target=write_File, args=('test1.txt',))
t2.start()
t2.join()
end = timeit.default_timer()
print(end - start)
input('enter to exit')
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong. You fell victim to Python's [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Only one thread can use the interpreter at a time so really under the hood of CPython programs multiple cores have to share one instance of the python interpreter.

Python threads switch when one goes to sleep or is awaiting I/O. So you would achieve a performance benefit from tasks such as

```
def do_connect():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(('python.org', 80))  # drop the GIL

for i in range(2):
    t = threading.Thread(target=do_connect)
    t.start()
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but why it took more time with threads? Also, no performance benefit can be achieved with Python's thread?

Comment: In Python, if you want to improve performance by conducting multiple CPU-intensive tasks in parallel then [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) (i.e. the creation of multiple processes) is _in general_ the best option, as each Python process will have its own GIL.